# What is an LCD-suitable proportional serif font with distinct 1, l , I, |, 0, and O, with normal, bold, and italic?

Tags: fonts

I prefer serif to sans serif fonts for body text, and I want distinct ell, one, capital eye, vertical, zero, and capital oh characters (l, 1 ,I, |, 0, O).

Distinct parentheses, curly braces, and angle brackets ({<>}) are a bonus.

The display will always be conventional middle-end 1280 x 1024 monitors.

Commercial solutions are acceptable.

Suggestions on how to search for such fonts are welcome.

Any problem-domain-specific vocabulary would be useful. Is there a *name* for fonts that have distinct glyphs?

Comment: Where will you use such a font?

Comment: I will use a font in an environment where there are many non-dictionary character strings, such as system names and automatically-generated unique identifiers, and where parentheses and curly braces are nearly equally distributed, have distinct semantics, and where lOad(name1), lOad<namel>, and l0ad{name} are all valid syntaxes which must be reproduced exactly without copy-paste.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would recommend heartily one of my favorite font - [Adobe Garamond Pro](http://www.adobe.com/type/browser/P/P_1703.html). :) Lovely, absolutely lovely booktype font that is bound to inspire old-school confidence in anyone.

[image]

Comment: Er... pardonnez-moi, for showing your spelling and grammar mistakes.

Comment: "Parens" isn't a word yet?

Comment: Parentheses, yes. Parens, no. :)

Comment: But then again, what's in a name? That which we call a rose by any other name would smell as sweet.

Comment: ... or parentheses, by any other name, just as curly.

Comment: Or maybe it does count; MS Word's dictionary is terrible. It has "equilibrium", but not “equilibria”. It does, however, have “equilibriums”.

Comment: +1 for the excellent example, and excellent comments to match :)

Comment: acceptible at books.google.com http://books.google.com/books?as_q=acceptible&num=10&btnG=Google+Search&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_brr=0&as_pt=ALLTYPES&lr=lang_en&as_vt=&as_auth=&as_pub=&as_sub=&as_drrb_is=b&as_minm_is=1&as_miny_is=1770&as_maxm_is=12&as_maxy_is=1922&as_isbn=&as_issn=

Comment: I just swapped out the image for one without all the squiggly underlines

Comment: "bound to inspire old-school confidence in anyone" what does that even mean?

Answer (score 5):

There must be hundreds of fonts that fit your requirements, selecting just one is down to your personal preferences.

Just listing from the ones I have installed:

1. Baskersville
2. Chaparral Pro
3. Cochin (l and 1 are pretty close...)
4. DejaVu Serif
5. Didot
6. Georgia (super distinct, digits are smaller)
7. Hoefler Text (same distinction)
8. LYNN (l and 1 are close again)
9. Minion Pro
10. Palatino (pretty wide but legible)
11. Times and Times New Roman (l and 1 are the closest yet... so probably not good)
12. Adobe Caslon Pro
13. Adobe Garamond Pro

Of these I'd only rule out Times and Times New Roman.

There's a chance that looking at [myfont.com's serif section](http://new.myfonts.com/tags/serif/) with the sample text "1Il| ()<>{} nm uvw UVW S5 gq9 oO0" set to fit to width could help you. But after a while they all look the same. You could go with the super distinct OCR-A type font if you didn't want something pretty.

Comment: I think I read the phrase "proofreading font" somewhere today while I was Google-searching.  Is that a term-of-art for "font where the glyphs are distinct"?  Is there a a Knuth value I can set to maximum?

Comment: I am unable to address your second and third question; I do not know how to search for fonts, nor do I know the term for clear distinctions between glyphs. I can only mildly recommend http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/